# Increasing size of image in UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

Currently, I have a `UIButton` and want to set an image inside of it. I'm successfully able to set the image to inside the UIButton but for some reason, the image is VERY small compared to the UIButton. I want to increase the size of the image - no, not cover the entire button just a slight increase so it's a bit more visible on the UI.

More information, my UIButton is `40x40`. The answers I've seen on StackOverFlow have indicated changing the `Content Mode` but even those answers have not helped. I'm a little stuck at this point so any expertise/advice would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I had to use `image insets`. This property allows to reposition the drawing rectangle for the button image. By setting values to the top, bottom, left, and right image insets we're creating a rectangle and thus, increasing the space for our image to be draw in.

I had actually seen this suggestion in other answers and had tried it but on IB, nothing seemed to change but I finally decided to test it on simulator and saw the affects.